# How to use i18n in Next.js without i18n routing?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, routes, internationalization

From v10 `Next.js` supports **i18n routing**. We should use i18n routing if we want to use i18n in Next.js. But my app doesn't need i18n routing.

> How do people developing SaaS with Next.js use i18n?

Comment: There are a few i18n libraries you can use ([next-i18next](https://github.com/isaachinman/next-i18next), [next-translate](https://github.com/vinissimus/next-translate), [react-intl](https://formatjs.io/docs/getting-started/installation/)). Out of curiosity, if you're not using i18n routing how does your app know what translations to display?

Comment: I'd say Next.js can know language from Accept-Language header and cookie.

Comment: Yes, but you need to enable Next.js i18n routing for that to work.